# Integrate google analytics to powerbi

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I have a website that is already generated from power bi and i need to track traffic of this website using google analytics, how can i do that? all the links that i found let me draw google analytics (of another website) in a new dashboard in power bi:
i found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-google-analytics and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-google-analytics-connector but that is not what i need

Comment: Are you trying to track the actual power bi dashboards using GA?

Comment: @XTOTHEL yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

First, here are the [general instructions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) for installing GA on a website.

I think there are two options available based on power bi's capabilities.

**Modifying the power bi templates**
This depends on if yu can modify the core power bi themes/templates to include the tracking script.

**Embed power bi data**
If you have a site that you can embed power bi data, then you can again, include the tracking code from GA on the pages.

Comment: i cannot embed power bi in another website, so do you have an idea how can i add a script in the power bi?

Comment: are you only looking for pageviews?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Are you talking about the Power BI Reporting Server product? As well as, are you only interested in seeing the reports people are looking at, not stuff like if they're interacting with any of the graphs/charts?

Comment: well actually i need all the info that google analytics can give me about the power bi dashboard